# Are there any jenkins variables for maven builds?

Tags: maven, jenkins

I am in need of accessing data that is produced through a maven build during a run on Jenkins which is then used in a curl command. This ultimately sends a message to a bot to post in a chat room. Plugins are not an option for this particular chat client unless I would be the one to make them. Any other plugins that would be able to execute curl or hit url are fine given I can get to the data.

Currently when I run the command

```
mvn surefire-report:report
```

I am able to see output like this from the job:

```
...
Results :

Failed tests:  
  passwordLengthRequirement(test.java.com.company.appium.suites.RegistrationTest): expected:<P[assword must be 6 characters or longer].> but was:<P[lease accept the Terms of Service].>
...
Tests in error:
  SendText(test.java.com.company.appium.suites.ChatTest): Timed out after 10 seconds waiting for presence of element located by: By.xpath: //window[2]/UIAKeyboard[1]/UIAKey[5]
...
Tests run: 40, Failures: 3, Errors: 2, Skipped: 4

[ERROR] There are test failures.

Please refer to .../target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< maven-surefire-report-plugin:2.16:report (default-cli) @ ios_junit <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-report-plugin:2.16:report (default-cli) @ ios_junit ---
[WARNING] Unable to locate Test Source XRef to link to - DISABLED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 17:26.412s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Jan 13 11:19:25 EST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Recording test results
```

If there are variables that can be used to get the data that would be a huge help but I don't know what they are if they even exist. My latest attempt has been to use the **Post Build Task** plugin to access the build.xml or log files with completed output. When trying to grep the build.xml that is created and extract the data I need grep is not working for some reason

XML:

```
`<failCount>72</failCount>`
`<skipCount>4</skipCount>`
`<totalCount>76</totalCount>`
```

Command:

```
$FAIL_COUNT=grep "failCount" ../../builds/$BUILD_NUMBER/build.xml | cut -d">" -f2,2 | cut -d"<" -f1,1
```

Output:

```
+ =grep failCount ../../builds/25/build.xml
/var/folders/2b/jv3l9cys1sqbbk6l2hxx_n1000007c/T/hudson6366869578068337646.sh: line 3: =grep: command not found
```

This page has been helpful with getting other variables but does not list what could be available during a maven run
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-JenkinsSetEnvironmentVariables

The message I am ultimately trying to send would be something like

```
Finished with status '$BUILD_STATUS'. Total tests run '$TOTAL_COUNT'. Total failed tests '$FAIL_COUNT'.
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Have you been able to find an answer to this topic?

Comment: Unfortunately I have not. Only options I can think of now are to capture the log output and parse it with another script once it completes. If run on Jenkins it captures the logs for you so that part is at least done.